# How to remove all spaces before and after a string in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string with spaces before and after it:

```
string str = "     hello world        ";
```

How can I remove all spaces before and after the "`hello world`"? But not the space between `hello world`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Trim function

```
string str = "     hello world        ";
str=str.Trim();
```

Trim removes the spaces from both the ends only not in between

Answer (score 2):

use can call `Trim()` function on your string  to `remove` all `white spaces` in your string.

Try This:

```
str=str.Trim();
```